# Why does Django/Postgres appear to save but doesn't, gives 'connection already closed'?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, wsl-2

I'm using Django + Postgres on Windows 10 WSL Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.  Saving data to postgres seems to work, yet when I access the table using psql on the command line, the data isn't there.  Refreshing the webpage (reloading Django) also shows the old data previous to the save.

There are no errors in the postgresql log.

I don't have caching explicitly turned on in Django's settings.py.

It all worked perfectly for years, but to be sure I upgraded Django to 3.2.6, Python to 3.8.11, postgresql to 12, and psycopg2 to 2.9.1, plus the necessary dependencies.  Same result.

Here's the code in Django:

```
    try:
        nodeToUpdate.save()  # Hit the database.
        node = Node.objects.get(pk=itemID, ofmap=mapId)  # Retrieve again to confirm it was saved
        # This shows the correct data:
        print("STORE TO MAP:" + str(node.ofmap_id) + " NODE:" + str(node.id) + " label:" + str(node.label))
    except psycopg2.InterfaceError as err:
        print(str(err))
        raise Exception(err)
    except ValidationError as err:
        raise Exception(err)
```

**The clue to what's going on comes when I run unit tests:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/mysite/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/var/www/mysite/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/mysite/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 236, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
**psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed**
```

But this InterfaceError exception isn't caught in the code I showed above.

I tried setting CONN_MAX_AGE in Django settings, didn't make a difference, so I removed it.

Online searches of this error have only brought up solutions in other types of environments, usually from several years ago.

Could it be due to a Windows upgrade of WSL2?  Nothing has come up in google searches.

**UPDATE**:  I just noticed that the apache logs are gone (I'm using 'django runserver' for the above, instead of apache, so I didn't notice).  postgres logs are all new since I started debugging this issue.  postgres sql dumps that I've done in the past are gone.  Luckily, my source code in /var/www remains.  Possibly a WSL update issue?

Comment: "But this InterfaceError exception isn't caught in the code I showed above." -> is it reported at all, outside of unit tests?

Comment: @snakecharmerb  Not that I've found, but see the update I've added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed" appears whenever there's an error in the code being unit tested before it gets to the assertion check in the test.  It's not a psycopg2 error, per se.  A non-intuitive message, to say the least.

*I'm open to suggestions on how to do unit testing in Django in which such errors are exposed and their location given in the source code, not just in the tests*.  I found them by process of elimination: commenting out tests and stepping through code with [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

My test classes are all subclassed from  django.test.TestCase since they query  Models in places.  From the [django unit testing docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/):

> If your tests rely on database access such as creating or querying
> models, be sure to create your test classes as subclasses of
> django.test.TestCase rather than unittest.TestCase.
>
> Using unittest.TestCase avoids the cost of running each test in a
> transaction and flushing the database, but if your tests interact with
> the database their behavior will vary based on the order that the test
> runner executes them. This can lead to unit tests that pass when run
> in isolation but fail when run in a suite.